# Check Plastic SCM reposity size on disk

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

How can I know how much disk space is occupying a Plastic SCM repository?

Answer (score 5):

It **depends on the backend** you have [configured](http://plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#Chapter8:Databasesetup) (SQL Server, MySQL, Firebird, etc... ).

Once you know the backend you're using, the problem is as simple as knowing **the size of the databases** in that backend. Plastic SCM databases starts with the prefix:

```
rep_X.plastic
```

where X is a numeric id.